# Apache Solr 6.4.1 Qtime is much more than Qtime of the same query in Solr 3.6.1

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, solrj, solr6

please any one help me !! 
when i run facet query in solr 6.4.1 the query takes around 5.5 seconds 
and when running the same query on solr 3.6.1 it takes around 3 seconds

the Two solrs run on the same environment and each server run on 8 gigabyte RAM .

Note : i disabled fieldCache for the two versions and using facet.method.enum .

can any one help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the solution of this problem  : 
adding **facet.threads**  parameter (Controls parallel execution of field faceting) to the query
e.g facet.threads=n  where n is the number of threads depending on your server specifications .
reference:https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting.